# A way to identify SmartGWT SelectItem in Selenium Grid 2 (WebDriver) tests

Tags: gwt, selenium-webdriver, smartgwt, selenium-grid

I am trying to set an ID to a SelectItem (to its options list, more precisely) in order to be able to identify it during Selenium Grid 2 tests and find no way to do it. What I need is to find the list and select (click) a value on it.

Tried and failed intents:

1. The usual methods for this purpose `setID()` and `ensureDebugId()` are not available in SelectItem
2. The method `setName()` don't leave any trace in the generated HTML
3. It is impossible to find the options list on the form that contains the SelectItem.
   SelectItem consists of separate elements:

   - **label**(title)
   - **textInput**(selected value)
   - **picker**(button to display the options drop-down list)
   - **pickList**(the options drop-down list)

   If you set an ID to the form that contains this component in order to localize it through `className` you can't spot the **pickList**, as it's getting generated when the picker is clicked and the generated code is placed out of the form bounds, so you can't find it within the form. It is possible to find it on the whole document, but in case of having more than one lists there is no way to know which list belongs to which SelectItem.

Any advice is welcome. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**: I would like to clarify something to avoid misunderstandings: I know that there are plenty different opinions about the different Selenium tools and versions and the best ways to use it with Smart GWT. This question is not entering these discussions. It is limited to the boundaries indicated in the question title: Selenium Grid 2 tests with WebDriver.

Some background: When coding our GWT components, we identify some of them (carefully, no duplications) with `setID()` method for testing purposes, we don't care that these identifiers may be read in the resulting HTML. (Using `ensureDebugId()` distorted our view, for some reason. Besides, Isomorphic guys recommended to forget it, anyway.) But `setID()` is not available for `FormItem`, i.e. we could not set an ID to `SelectItem` (which extends from `FormItem`) in order to write a test where the first not empty option would be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I could find is that a `SelectItem` lets you set the picker icon name, something that we never used and/or needed:

```
selectItemInstance.setPickerIconName("someName");
```

This name is later present in the generated HTML. So we decided to make use of it and assign this way an ID, just like in case of `setID()`. The `WebDriver` methods allow you later find the `SelectItem` element by this name following these steps:

1) find the form (that has the `SelectItem` element inside) by its ID

2) find all the `SelectItem` elements inside the form

`formElement.findElements(By.className("selectItemControl"));`

3) select the one that has the pickerIconName equal to the ID assigned with `setPickerIconName()` (looping through the found elements):

```
selectItemElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@*='" + pickerIconNameID + "']"));
```

4) when found, click on it to get the options list generated

```
pickerElement.click();
```

**NOTE:** The options list is generated ***not before the first click*** on the `SelectItem` element and then stays on, changing from visible to invisible. When generated, it is out of the boundaries of the form that contains the corresponding `SelectItem`. This may be a problem, because if you have more than one `SelectItem` elements in the window (which is likely), you have to find *the correct* options list. Several criterias might be applied to find it. We chose options list's location as the easiest and the most reliable one: the options list that "sticks" to the `SelectItem` element should be the right one.

5) find all the options lists on the window:

```
driver.findElementsByClassName("pickListMenuBody")
```

6) choose the right options list for the `SelectItem`: using `getLocation()` and `getSize()` methods of `WebElement`, check which of options list found intersects/touches the `SelectItem` element ("selectItemControl") found through *steps 2 and 3*

That's it, from here on just choose the necessary item in the "listTable" (contained inside the options list element, i.e. "pickListMenuBody"), as you probably did more than once.

Remember to take the loading time into account when searching for elements and keep your utility/infrastructure code separated from test code, otherwise this will become a mess.

This is not the most elegant solution, but it works for us and I am sure that the GWT and Selenium teams, in time, will offer something better.

Any comments and suggestions (limited to the use of Selenium Grid 2) are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of documentation on how to use Selenium with Smart GWT here:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/UsingSelenium.html

You don't want to be using approaches like you discussed.  The DOM that is generated by Smart GWT is considered internal details, and instead of working directly with the DOM we give you a much more powerful approach based on abstract locators.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but your response doesn't answer my question. May be I explained myself not good enough, but the point is that
the approach that I discussed **IS** the way recommended on the page that you link; it says: _"One primary locator is based on the ID of the Smart GWT widget"_. I am not using it with Selenium IDE, but in automated tests with Selenium Grid 2 (WebDriver). In order to locate an widget by its locator GWT lets you assign this ID when coding your components. I am not working directly with the DOM, I use RemoteWebDriver to find the element.

Comment: I tried to do the same - select an option from SelectItem option list - with Selenium IDE, as a reference tool on the page that you linked, in order to see how it handles it. No way. Selenium IDE can't "see" it either, it is unable to record a click with reference to the list (i.e. pointing to its scLocator).